# Filter Single JSON by Key Name

Tags: javascript, json

I want to create some type of Laravel's `only` method in JS.

I have the following JSON:

```
let obj = {
             name: "Wil",
             age: "20",
             id: "1"
          }
```

And a **filters** array:

```
let filters = ['name', 'age'];
```

In this case i want a function that takes 2 parameters:

```
const filterJSON = (object, filters) => {

}
```

And i want the function to return the same object with ONLY the key  names i pass in the filters array.

In this case:

```
{
   name: "Wil",
   age: "20"
}
```

I have a while trying with `.map` and `.filter` but i'm not getting what i want, the examples i found are only with array of objects, but in this case i need to filter a single object.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use a simple `reduce()` to return a new object

```js
let obj = { name: "Wil",age: "20",id: "1"}
let filters = ['name', 'age'];

const filterJSON = (obj, fil) => fil.reduce((a,c) => (a[c] = obj[c], a),{})


console.log(filterJSON(obj, filters))
```

Comment: This solution is great!! I loved it, but can you explain me this part? `(a[c] = obj[c], a)`, this is the same as `return (a[c] = obj[c], a)` right? Why are you returning 2 params?

Comment: More like `fil.reduce((a,c) =>{a[c] = obj[c]; return  a},{})`. I'm taking advantage of the *comma operator* in the shorter syntax to return the `a`

Comment: Try this `console.log((1,7))` ... logs `7` because of the comma operator

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a lot sir.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.keys` and `reduce`

```js
const obj = {
  name: "Wil",
  age: "20",
  id: "1"
}

let filters = ['name', 'age'];

const filterJSON = (object, filters) => Object.keys(object).reduce((a, v) => {
  if (filters.some(f => f === v)) {
    a[v] = object[v];
  }
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(filterJSON(obj, filters));
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new object, then loop through the array and add key and value using square bracket notation from the object

```js
let obj = {
  name: "Wil",
  age: "20",
  id: "1"
}
let filters = ['name', 'age'];

function getObj(arr, obj) {

  let newObj = {};
  filters.forEach(function(elem) {
    newObj[elem] = obj[elem]
  })
  return newObj;
};

console.log(getObj(filters, obj))
```